# HttpURLConnection does not return Response code

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am working with a java based desktop application where am trying to open a HttpURLconnection to our own rest API. This connection returns the response if I run it from the eclipse IDE. But the same code is not returning the response code (getting stuck for ever at connection.getResponseCode()) when am running it from the application executable. I tried with different proxies thinking it could be a proxy issue. But no luck :( 
And the weird thing is, it is happening in only few systems. In other systems it is working fine with executables
Please help me out here. Thanks in advance

Comment: And if you try to access the API from a browser on that computers does it work? Just to rule out any connectivity issues. Also make sure that any interfering software (proxies, anti-viruses) are disabled while testing this out.

Comment: Yes, it works from browser

Comment: Any antivirus or proxy software running on that computer? It's good to turn off everything that may interfere.

Comment: I tried by disabling anti-virus software. Still did not work

Comment: Honestly, I'm lost. As a last resort I'd try `curl`. Or telnet on port 80 just to see it working: `telnet www.apiserver.com 80`.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with JVM. I am using different JVM in eclipse and executable. Tried by replacing the JVM in exe with the one in eclipse and it worked. Still need to analyse why it is not working with the other JVM.